# Rsyslog - Parsing audit.log / omprog change log value

Tags: bash, syslog, rsyslog, linux-audit, module

I'm trying to parse audit.log with rsyslog by using a bash script in order to transform the hex part of proctitle to ascii. However I do not get ressults: the file audit_ascii.log do not have lines with "proctitle" values. I tested the script and it is working fine so I guess the problem comes from my rsyslog.conf.

**rsyslog.conf:**

```
$InputFileName /var/log/audit/audit.log
$InputFileTag tag_auditd:
$InputFileStateFile log_audit
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor

if $msg contains "msg=audit" then {
action(type="omprog" binary="/bin/bash /opt/bin/hex2ascii.sh" output="/var/log/audit/audit_ascii.log")
```

**hex2ascii**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    read log
    
    hasHex=$(echo $log | egrep "msg=audit" | egrep "type=PROCTITLE" | egrep -v '"' | wc -c)
    
    if [ ${hasHex} -gt 0 ];
    then
        part1=$(echo $log | cut -d"=" -f1-3)
    
        part2=$(echo $log | cut -d"=" -f4)
        part2=$(echo $part2 | xxd -r -p )
        echo $part1 >> /var/log/audit/verif.txt 
        #echo "${part1}=${part2}\n" >> /var/log/audit/audit_ascii.log
        log="${part1}=${part2}\n"
    #else
        #echo $log >> /var/log/audit/audit_ascii.log
            
    fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stop the flow after the script redirected the changed log to another file. Then I take the new file as another input in rsyslog. Best solution I found

Answer (score 0):

Though several modules are built-in to rsyslog, some of them are not and need to be loaded before they can be used.

The `imfile` module you are using needs to be preceded by the line (in legacy syntax):

```
$ModLoad imfile
```

Similarly, the [omprog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html) module, if using the newer syntax, needs

```
module(load="omprog")
```

before it can be used in the `if` statement (which is missing a closing `}`).
Look at the error messages you will get from `rsyslogd -N 1`.

Comment: The module is already present in the rsyslog.conf. In fact it is working only when it comes to execute the script and writing logs which are not composed of "proctitle". I wish the script worked for "proctitle" logs and it would be perfect if I just could modify the $log in the script and then rsysog could directly write it it to my output. For the moment, I can't get any result from the "output" of omprog